# Multiprocessing does not see global variables?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, global

I have run into a strange behaviour at multiprocessing.

When i try to use a global variable in a function which is called from multiprocessing it does not see a global variable.

Example:

```
import multiprocessing

def func(useless_variable):
    print(variable)

useless_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
variable = "asd"

func(useless_list)

for x in p.imap_unordered(func, useless_list):
    pass
```

Output:

```
asd
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "pywork/asd.py", line 4, in func
    print(variable)
NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pywork/asd.py", line 11, in <module>
    for x in p.imap_unordered(func, useless_list):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 689, in next
    raise value
NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
```

As you see the first time i just simply call `func` it print `asd` as expected. However when i call the very same function with multiprocessing it says the variable `variable` does not exists, even after i clearly printed it just before.

Does multiprocessing ignore global variables? How can i work this around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multiprocessing` `Pool`s fork (or spawn in a way intended to mimic forking on Windows) its worker processes at the moment the `Pool` is created. `fork`ing maps the parent memory as copy-on-write in the children, but it doesn't create a persistent tie between them; after the `fork`, changes made in the parent are not visible in the children, and vice versa. You can't use any variables defined after the `Pool` was created, and changes made to variables from before the `Pool` was created will not be reflected in the workers.

Typically, with a `Pool`, you want to avoid mutable global state entirely; have all the data needed passed to the function you're `imap`-ing (or whatever) as arguments (which are serialized and sent to the children, so the state is correct), and have the function `return` any new data instead of mutating globals, which serializes it and sends it back to the parent process to use as it sees fit.

`Managers`s are an option, but not usually the correct option with `Pool`s; you usually want to stick to workers only looking at read only globals from before the `Pool` was created, or working with arguments and returning new values, not using global state at all.

Comment: Ah, thank you. The key point about  the memory being copied when the pool is created is not noted anywhere else that I have looked.

Answer (score 1):

When you spam a process all context is copyed, you need to get use of [`managers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) for exachanging objects between them, check the [official documentations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), for managing state check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).